# Pytorch Train & Eval Different Sample Sizes

Tags: python, pytorch

I am learning pytorch, and have the following (abbreviated) code to setup for modeling:

```
# define the model class for a neural net with 1 hidden layer
class myNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_in, H, D_out):
        super(myNN, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(D_in,H)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(H,D_out)
    def forward(self,X):
        return torch.sigmoid(self.lin2(torch.sigmoid(self.lin1(x))))

# now make the datasets & dataloaders
batchSize = 5
# Create the data class
class Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = torch.FloatTensor(x)
        self.y = torch.Tensor(y.astype(int))
        self.len = self.x.shape[0]
        self.p = self.x.shape[1]
    def __getitem__(self, index):      
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
trainData = Data(trnX, trnY)
trainLoad = DataLoader(dataset = trainData, batch_size = batchSize)
testData = Data(tstX, tstY)
testLoad = DataLoader(dataset = testData, batch_size = len(testData))

# define the modeling objects
hiddenLayers = 30
learningRate = 0.1
model = myNN(p,hiddenLayers,1)
print(model)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = learningRate)
loss = nn.BCELoss()
```

with `trnX.shape=(70, 2)`, `trnY.shape=(70,)`, `tstX.shape=(30,2)`, and `tstY.shape=(30,)`. The code for training is:

```
# train!
epochs = 1000
talkFreq = 0.2
trnLoss = [np.inf]*epochs
tstLoss = [np.inf]*epochs
for i in range(epochs):
    # train with minibatch gradient descent
    for x, y in trainLoad:
        # forward step
        yhat = model(x)
        # compute loss (not storing for now, will do after minibatching)
        l = loss(yhat, y)
        # backward step
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        l.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    # evaluate loss on training set
    yhat = model(trainData.x)
    trnLoss[i] = loss(yhat, trainData.y)
    # evaluate loss on testing set
    yhat = model(testData.x)
    tstLoss[i] = loss(yhat, testData.y)
```

The datasets `trainData` and `testData` have 70 and 30 observations, respectively. This is probably just a newbie problem, but when I run the training cell, it errors on the `trnLoss[i] = loss(yhat, trainData.y)` line with the error

```
ValueError: Target and input must have the same number of elements. target nelement (70) != input nelement (5)
```

When I inspect the output of the `yhat=model(trainData.x)` line, I see that `yhat` is a tensor with `batchSize` elements, despite the fact that `trainData.x.shape = torch.Size([70, 2])`.

How can I iteratively train the model with the minibatch gradient descent, then use the model to compute the loss & accuracy on the full training & testing sets? I tried setting `model.train()` just before the mini batch iteration, then `model.eval()` just before the evaluation code, to no avail.

Comment: What is `p` in `model = myNN(p,hiddenLayers,1)`? Also keep the `model.eval()` before `yhat = model(trainData.x)` and the `model.train()` before that `for x, y`

Comment: I have `p=2`. I currently have the `model.train()` and `model.eval()` calls in the places you suggested.

Comment: (by "currently", I mean I had added those lines, but still go the error...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `myNN.forward()`, you are passing lower case `x` as input to `self.lin1` while input parameter to the function is named as capital case `X`. Small case `x` is kind of global variable defined at for loop for `trainload` hence you are not getting any syntax error, but the value that you intend to pass is not being passed to `self.lin1`.

Might I also suggest that you should consider using `model.eval()` and `with torch.no_grad()` for your testing code. It is not absolutely necessary here but it will make more sense.

Comment: Thank you, correcting that `X` to `x` fixed the problem. The fact that the `forward()` evaluation of the model was reading the most recent value for `x` as a "global" var, explained why `yhat` was of length `batchSize`, despite the input. Regarding your last point, I should put all my eval code (from `model.eval()` to the end of the loop) inside `with torch.no_grade()`, right? Last question, should I be writing `model.eval()`, or `model = model.eval()` as I saw in some places online. Thanks!

Comment: 1: yes, it's generally a good practice to write all your evaluation code inside `with torch.no_grad()` block as we do not wish to calculate gradients during evaluation. 2: Calling `model.eval()` is  enough. make sure that you also call `model.train()` at the start of "epoch for loop" in order to set model in train mode before looping over `trainLoad`.